# Error "unexpected keyword argument 'max_lengh" en Django 2.2.2

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

estoy intentando realizar una migración del fichero **models.py** de la una app y al ejecutar el comando:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

me aparece el siguiente error:

[image: Error ejecución python manage.py migrate]

El código del fichero **models.py** en donde genero las tablas contiene el siguiente código:

**CODIGO PACIENTE:**

```py
from django.db import models
from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField

# Create your models here.
class Paciente(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    apellido_Paterno = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    apellido_Materno = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    rut = models.IntegerField(max_length=8)
    fecha_Nacimiento = models.DateField()
    sexos = (('F','Femenino'),('M','Masculino'))
    sexo = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=sexos, default='M')
    descripcion_paciente = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="No presenta anotaciones importantes")
    enfermedades_Previas= (
        ('EP1Hipertención Arterial','Hipertención Arterial'),
        ('Diabetes','Diabetes'),
        ('TIB. C','TIB. C'),
        ('Accidentes Vasculares','Accidentes Vasculares'),
        ('Alergias a comidas','Alergias a comidas'),
        ('Ninguna','Ninguna')
        )
    enfermedad_Previa = MultiSelectField(max_length=40, choices=enfermedades_Previas, default="Ninguna")
    nivelesNeurologicos = (
        ('Lenguaje conservado','Lenguaje conservado'),
        ('Contenido adecuado','Contenido adecuado'),
        ('Se alimenta solo(a)','Se alimenta solo(a)'),
        ('Controla Esfinteres','Controla Esfinteres'),
        ('Es agresivo','Es agresivo'),
        ('Lee','Lee'),
        ('Ninguno','Ninguno')
        )
    nivelNeurologico = MultiSelectField(max_length=40, choices=nivelesNeurologicos, default="Ninguno")

    def NombreCompleto(self):
        cadena = "{0} {1}, {2}"
        return cadena.format(self.Apellido_Paterno, self.Apellido_Materno, self.Nombre)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.NombreCompleto()
```

**CODIGO TUTOR:**

```py
class Tutor(models.Model):
    nombre_tutor = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    apellido_Paterno_tutor = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    apellido_Materno_tutor = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    rut_tutor = models.IntegerField(max_length=8)
    sexos = (
        ('F','Femenino'),
        ('M','Masculino')
        )
    sexo = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=sexos, default='M')
    telefono_tutor = models.IntegerField(max_length=9)
    direccion_tutor = models.CharField(max_lenght=50)
    correo_tutor = models.EmailField(max_length=80)

    def NombreCompletoTutor(self):
        cadena = "{0} {1}, {2}"
        return cadena.format(self.apellido_Paterno_tutor, self.apellido_Materno_tutor, self.nombre_tutor)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.NombreCompletoTutor()
```

[image: Apps]

***NOTA 2:*** Instalé un módulo par adjango de multiselect. es por eso que se importa, para poder hacer uso de este.

Espero me puedan ayudar, quedo atento a ante cualquier comentario.

Comment: Contenía un error en la escritura.
Algunas filas tenía escrito `max_lenght` cuando la forma correcta era `max_length`.
reemplace por la forma correcta y pude realizar la migración.